# Javascript, have links all auto open in new tabs

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very simple javascript which turns book isbns in to clickable URL links to Amazon.com. What I am trying to do is add a function that when "clicked" opens all the URL links in new tabs. This saves me the time of clicking every single link.

Is this doable? =)

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<div><b>ISBN Hyperlinker</b></div>
<textarea id=numbers placeholder="paste isbn numbers as csv here" style="width:100%" rows="8" >

</textarea>
<div><b>Hyperlinked text:</b></div>
<div id="output" style="white-space: pre"></div>



<script>


//the input box.
var input = document.getElementById('numbers');
var output = document.getElementById('output')
var base = 
    'https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords='



//adding an event listener for change on the input box
input.addEventListener('input', handler, false);

//function that runs when the change event is emitted
function handler () {
  var items = input.value.split(/\b((?:[a-z0-9A-Z]\s*?){10,13})\b/gm);
  // Build DOM for output
  var container = document.createElement('span');
  items.map(function (item, index) {
    if (index % 2) { // it is the part that matches the split regex:
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.textContent = item.trim();
      link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
      link.setAttribute('href', base + item);
      container.appendChild(link);
    } else { // it is the text next to the matches
      container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item))
    }
  });
  // Replace output
  output.innerHTML = '';
  output.appendChild(container);
}
handler(); // run on load


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You could try using `window.open(url);` instead of creating new `a` 's.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) event manually, like:

```
  container.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
```

But that's just an example to show you easily that it would work with your given code. I would suggest having a button like "Open All Links" and having that button use a selector to gather up all the links and then loop through them and call the `click` method on each one. You would be making things easier on yourself giving the outer container (the output div) an ID that you could use as the initial outer selector.